# N Queens program using stack and backtracking

Tags: java, stack, backtracking

I'm trying write a program (for homework) that has a nxn board and I need the algorithm to find all the possible solutions to having n number of queens in a position in which none of the queens can capture each other. So the code I have now looks like this.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class NQueens {

  public static int solve(int n) {
      Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();

      int  current = 0;
      int numSolutions = 0;
      while(!(current>n)){
          if(s.size() == n){
              break;
          }
          if(current == n){
              if((s.peek()==n) && (s.size() == 1)){
                  break;
              }
              if(s.peek() == n){
                  s.pop();
                  current = s.pop()+1;
              }
              else{
                  current = s.pop()+1;
              }
          }
          else if(validPositionChecker(s, current)){
              s.push(current);
              current = 0;
          }
          else{
              current++;
          }
      }
      if(s.size()==n){
          printSolution(s);
          numSolutions++
      }

      return numSolutions;
      }
  public static boolean validPositionChecker(Stack<Integer> s, int currentPosition) {
      for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
          if (s.get(i) == currentPosition){
              return false;
          }
          if ((s.get(i) - currentPosition) == (s.size() - i)){
              return false;   
          }
          if ((currentPosition - s.get(i)) == (s.size() - i)){
              return false;   
          }
      }
      return true;
  }
  //this method prints out a solution from the current stack


  private static void printSolution(Stack<Integer> s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i ++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < s.size(); j ++) {
        if (j == s.get(i))
          System.out.print("Q ");
        else
          System.out.print("* ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();  
  }//printSolution()


  public static void main(String[] args) {

      int n = 8;

      // pass in parameter n from command line
      if (args.length == 1) {
        n = Integer.parseInt(args[0].trim());
        if (n < 1) {
          System.out.println("Incorrect parameter");
          System.exit(-1);
        }//if   
      }//if

      int number = solve(n);
      System.out.println("There are " + number + " solutions to the " + n + "-queens problem.");
  }//main()

}
```

So to explain this code. This code works. But it only prints out one of the solutions. In the default nxn board of 8x8 it should have 92 unique solutions.

My question is how do I get it to print all the solutions. I understand that I can use another while on top of my given while loop in the solve method, but I dont know what parameters to give the while loop for it to exit. Basically to reiterate, I need to know in what conditions do I know when the bigger while loop would stop when it's found all the solutions.

I have to use stack and I cannot use recursion for this homework. Recursion would have made it much simpler.

Comment: When you in order to proceed you need to place the 1st queen into `(n+1)` position.

Comment: You should not add another loop--it will find the same solution again. You need to NOT terminate when you find the first solution, but continue to find the others.

Comment: So ok, I make it so that once it finds a solution it will pop the last push and try to find the next solution. However, does the loop eventually stop? Will the loop break if its found all the solutions?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out. Thanks so much!

Comment: I wish I could give you more than just a comment upvote.

Comment: Classic Stack does not have methods like get(i)... Only peek(), push(), pop(), isEmpty(), size()... etc

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class QueenSolver {
private static final int NUM_QUEENS = 8;
private static int[] board = new int[NUM_QUEENS];

public static void solve(int n) {
    int current = 0;
    int numSolutions = 0;

    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<>();

    while (true) {
        while (current < n) {
            if (isBoardCorrect(s, current)) {
                s.push(current);
                board[s.size() - 1] = current;
                current = 0;
            } else {
                current++;
            }
        }

        if (s.size() == n) {
            printSolution(++numSolutions);
        }

        if (s.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }

        if (s.peek() == n) {
            s.pop();
        }

        current = s.pop() + 1;
    }
}

private static boolean isBoardCorrect(Stack<Integer> s, int currentPosition) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++) {
        if (board[i] == currentPosition
                || currentPosition == board[i]
                || Math.abs(currentPosition - board[i]) == s.size() - i) {

            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static void printSolution(int num) {
    System.out.print(num + ": ");
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("(" + i + "," + board[i] + ")");
        if (i < board.length - 1) {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    QueenSolver.solve(8);
}

}
```